# When it is a number display text center else display text left

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events

The numbers must center align and the text must left align

I'm getting a error in my code. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong

Image

[image]

Code

```js
color = color !== "" && color !== undefined ? " <span class=\"color\" style=\"background: #" + color + "\"></span>" : " <span class=\"color\"></span>";
contentHtml += "<td rowspan1=\"" + 1 + "\" class=\"" + (rowspan !== "" && rowspan > 1 ? "groups" : "") + " " + (typeof value == Number) ? "text-center" : "text-left" + "\">" + value + (Number(value) ? preFix : "") + color + (Number(value) ? postFix : "") + "</td>";
if (rowspan > 1) {
     var rowspanContent = "<td rowspan1=\"" + rowspan + "\" class=\"" + (rowspan !== "" && rowspan > 1 ? "groups" : "") + " " + (typeof value == Number) ? "text-center" : "text-left" + "\">" + value + (Number(value) ? preFix : "") + color + (Number(value) ? postFix : "") + "</td>"; }
```

Comment: *"Im getting a error in my code."* What error would that be?

Comment: Sorry i put it wrong im not getting a error in my code but im getting a error on  my datagrid look at the image

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ternary statement `(typeof value == Number) ? "text-center" : "text-left"` in brackets so that you have `... + ((typeof value == Number) ? "text-center" : "text-left") + ...` in both instances where you use it